# How to make video duotone effect in FFMPEG

Tags: video, filter, ffmpeg, gradient

Is it possible to make a video with a duotone effect in FFMpeg
As I understand I should apply gradient to video but I can't understand how make it via FFMpeg

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fmpeg -i INPUT -filter_complex \
  "[0:v]format=gray[v0];\
   gradients=s=256x1:c0=black:c1=green:x0=0:y0=0:x1=256:y1=0,trim=end_frame=1[v1];\
   [v0][v1]paletteuse" OUTPUT
```

Explanation of filters used:

- [`paletteuse`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#paletteuse): Use a palette to downsample an input video stream.
- [`gradients`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#gradients): Generate 1x256 gradient strip. Change `c0` and `c1` to set your 2 colors.
- [`format`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format-1): You need a grayscale video input
- `trim`: (maybe unnecessary) generate gradient only once.

Comment: In my case, I get an error: **"No such filter: 'gradients'"**. How comes? This is a standard FFmpeg filter ...

Comment: I think gradients filter was introduced fairly recently. Check your ffmpeg version. Grab the latest one